# Can not register content for intids

Tags: plone, dexterity

Part of the content of my plone site is missing intids. 
I have been trying to use registration function from plone.app.initd to register the missing intids as follows:

```
# running .bin/ipzope in the plone instance

from plone.app.intid import setuphandlers
setuphandlers.register_all_content_for_intids(portal)
```

The result i am getting is a report of registered and existing initds:

```
(201, 349)
```

How can I run the command so that it does what it's expected to do: register the missing intids?

Is there any other way to register intids with already existing content?